# On server Getting exception The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, email, authentication

I have a code where I am sending mail.When I send mail on my local host mails get send easily but when I upload my code to the server. I am getting this exception

```
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure
connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response
was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at at
System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode,
String response) at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection
conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode) at
System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender,
MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean
allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) at
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at
Admin_test.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
d:\hostingspaces\abd9009\ihmsgr.domainNames.net\wwwroot\info\test.aspx.cs:line
29
```

My code runs perfectly on my local machine and on other server but
doesnt work on your server is like this:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add("username@gmail.com");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("username@gmail.com", "Email
head", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        mail.Subject = "This mail is send from asp.net application";
        mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.Body = "This is Email Body Text";
        mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Credentials = new
System.Net.NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "MyPassword");
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        try
        {
            client.Send(mail);
             }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex);
}
}
```

I am using hosting space on Server http://www.arvixe.com/ PLEASE HELP

Comment: Delete this ASAP and repost WITHOUT YOUR GMAIL USERNAME AND PASSWORD IN THE CODE!!!

Comment: Modified dear with dummy username and password

Comment: You can still see your password in the revision history FYI. Probably easiest to change your password at this point. You should learn how to actually debug smtp traffic with wireshark and telnet, because you will probably have other issues.

Comment: I changed my password

Answer (score 1):

try this.

1) EnableSSL true or false

2) Check Credentials again

3) Sometimes certain SMTP servers (mainly for companies) don't allow external access or    havea separate IP for external access

4) Check whether the username should include the @Host.com or without it

I hope one of them works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Give a shot at this i have just faced this problem and solved mine may be a different scenario though. 
My client gave me his credentials for brand new noreply@hisSite.com then i have tried using them as credentials then i got this error as he has not logged into it at least for one time . I logged in and boom it worked

may be one of these things could help you

1. Try to login to your account and change password and set a new password( a strong one)
2. Try using mail.UseDefaultCredentials = false;